# Searching for files containing text (not string) in bash

Tags: bash, find, full-text-search

How do I find files containing some particular text containing newlines and plenty of other charachters all sorts of quotes and backslashes using terminal?

Comment: may be you should take a look at man pages of `egrep` to search with regular expression. As I do not know what exactly you're searching for, I can tell you this `find /dir -type f | xargs egrep '---' 
Replace `'---'` with actual regex

Comment: The problem is the search pattern is way too big for this. Specifically it's a piece of html code. Tried grep -F, but the passage contains non-unique lines, so the output is messy.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is somewhat line-based, so matching across line boundaries might be problematic with it. If you've the memory to spare, match against the whole file with e.g. `perl`:

```
$ (echo fish; echo cat; echo dog; echo frog) \
  | perl -0777 -nE 'say $1 if m/(cat.dog)/s'
```

The "all sorts of quotes and backslashes" bit will likely mostly be avoiding shell interpolation rules, e.g. via `'\''` type tricks or see `ascii(7)` and then in perl use an appropriate `\047` or `\x52` or whatever as necessary. Lacking the memory to load the file, `strings(1)` might first be used to reduce the amount of data to search.